# Special characters in sitecore item name (*)

Tags: sitecore

It is possible to create an item with *** name in sitecore.
this would allow to process any page name.

What would be if create * item, and one more (*) like a child item ?

What would be if create * item under bucket item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marek is right in his explanation (below). I would want to add couple more concerns to think about:

1. How would you make it **Page Editor** friendly?
2. How would address and **resolve datasources** (by URL? on the fly?). You have just one page item that handles all the matching page requests for multiple datasources.
3. How would you get **Page Not Found** (proper 404 status code) support, in case you do not have a datasource?

All that should be taken into consideration before you start implementation.
I wrote an article in attempt to answer those questions. Please read at:

http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/wildcard-items-pages-with-mvc-passing-the-correct-datasources-based-on-requested-item-url

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

You can create an item called `*` in Sitecore. Lets assume that your content tree is:

```
-home
  - item-a
  - item-b
    - item-c
    - *
  - *
    - item-d
    - *
```

If you hit url:

- `/` - home item is returned
- `/item-a` - `item-a` item is displayed
- `/item-b/item-c` - `item-c` is displayed
- `/item-b/something-else` - `/item-b/*` iten is displayed
- `/aaa` - `*` item is displayed
- `/bbb/ccc` - `*/*` item is displayed.

So if there is an item at given level with a name which matches url segment, this item will be used. In other case, Sitecore will check if there is a wildcard item (item with name `*`), and will continue with matching the next segment.

I've never tried with wildcard items in bucket - I don't think it make much sense there.

Comment: thanks Marek, I just want to keep this question available in google search. I agree about bucket it is sick to do  it. but theoretically interesting.